# Custom @Model property getter/setter in SwiftData

Tags: swift, swift-data

In Core Data I can implement a custom NSManagedObject property getter/setter:

```swift
@objc var name: String {
    get {
        willAccessValue(forKey: #keyPath(name))
        defer { didAccessValue(forKey: #keyPath(name)) }
        
        let name = primitiveValue(forKey: #keyPath(name)) as? String
        return name ?? ""
    }
    set {
        willChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(name))
        defer { didChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(name)) }
        
        // Trimming is just an example, it could be any data cleanup.
        let name = newValue.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        setPrimitiveValue(name, forKey: #keyPath(name))
    }
}
```

How to achieve that in a SwiftData `@Model`? I don't want to create a second property based on a persisted one but have only a single property.

Why not 2 properties:

- If I add the computed property later on then I need to migrate the data to a new stored property name like `_name` or choose a new, second-rate computed property name like `nameNew`.
- The stored property cannot be private because the computed property is not available in `#Predicate`.
- 1 property would be nicer because I don't really need 2 properties, I just want to clean the data in the setter.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if you ran into any problems with your above solution.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I deleted it because it doesn't even compile anymore. I don't think it ever worked.

Comment: Did you try using a computed property working against a private stored property?

Comment: That works but requires 2 properties. The stored property cannot be private because I need it for `#Predicate` since the computed property doesn't work there (so I use private(set) instead). Also, if I add the computed property later then I need to migrate the data or choose a new, second-rate name for it.

Comment: You could create a custom type that holds and always trims a string property but that is perhaps overkill, otherwise I believe you are confined to using two properties.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Why did yor answer disappear, was there a problem with it? While it might not have been ideal for my use case it could have worked for others and was definitely relevant. I won't accept my own answer.

Comment: I posted that solution because you clearly stated that using 2 properties was not acceptable and then when you post an answer using 2 properties after all I felt my answer was no longer relevant since the 2 properties solution is the one I think is the correct one and my answer was more of a work around.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an easy solution using a single property. But it's possible to address the pain points.

### Solution 1

```swift
@Attribute(originalName: "name")
private(set) var _name = ""

var name: String {
    get { _name }
    set { _name = newValue.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) }
}
```

- `@Attribute(originalName: "name")` is only needed if you change the stored property name from `name` to `_name` and have data to migrate. If you forget this, the data will be deleted. ⚠️
- `_name` is `private(set)` to ensure clean data via the `name` setter. It cannot be fully private because as a computed property `name` is not available in `#Predicate`.

### Solution 2

```swift
private(set) var name = ""

var name2: String {
    get { name }
    set { name = newValue.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) }
}
```

- The stored property retains its name, so no data migration is needed when you add the computed property later.
- The "2" in `name2` stands for two-way (get and set).